# Alias to git executable

Tags: git

I have [the git Github repository](https://github.com/git/git) cloned on a machine. I would like to alias `git` to an executable from somewhere in the git folder.

However, I can't find any executable.

Normally, I would alias to this:

```
alias git=/path/to/my/git/bin/git
```

But this won't work because there is no `bin` folder.

So how could I alias git? Where is the executable?

Comment: The repository you are referencing is the git source code. This needs to be compiled to get an executable.

Answer (score 1):

As @languitar pointed out, you only downloaded the source code

You have two options here:

1. Try and install git from source, something that may or may not work first try, and will be pretty time consuming. Take a look at the text file named INSTALL in the root directory of the git repository for more details.
2. Just download a git binary. They can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads).